# ignore touch events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I´m making a game with cocos2d and need to ignore touch events in some cases, esp. when another touch is "in progress".
It is, the player touches the screen, moves the finger around and then ends the touch. During this period, I need to ignore all other touches that may occur. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Wouldn´t that stop the "current, moving touch"? That needs to be continued with CCTouchesMoved etc., while another CCTouchesBegan should be ignored.